# How to disable security in Quarkus

Tags: java, security, rbac, quarkus, disable

I´ve implemented JWT RBAC in my Quarkus application, but I don´t want to provide tokens whenever I´m testing my application locally.

**EDIT:**

What I´ve tried so far are setting these properties to "false" without any effect.

```
quarkus.oauth2.enabled=false
quarkus.security.enabled=false
quarkus.smallrye-jwt.enabled=false
```

Currently I´ve commented out all of

```
 //@RolesAllowed({"user"})
```

to "disable" auth locally.

**Is there any property to disable security / enable endpoints for any given role?**

Comment: Have you tried `quarkus.[oauth|oidc].enabled=false`? All in all, I doubt that this is possible. Keep in mind that some endpoints may require information from the token (e.g. the logged in user).

Comment: @Turing85 at least oauth2,enabled=false, see my edit above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can implement an AuthorizationController (io.quarkus.security.spi.runtime.AuthorizationController)

```
public class DisabledAuthController extends AuthorizationController {
    @ConfigProperty(name = "disable.authorization")
    boolean disableAuthorization;

    @Override
    public boolean isAuthorizationEnabled() {
        return disableAuthorization;
    }
}
```

In Quarkus guides, you can find more information

https://quarkus.io/guides/security-customization#disabling-authorization

Comment: You can also define a property quarkus.security.auth.enabled-in-dev-mode=false for the same result, except the option only works in dev/test mode.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using MicroProfile JWT RBAC, so set this:
quarkus.smallrye-jwt.enabled=false

A broader FYI, you can [find the JWT RBAC properties here](https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config#quarkus-smallrye-jwt_quarkus-smallrye-jwt), in the context of all available properties too.

Comment: Thanks. I´ve tried that and it may indeed disable JWT, but my routes still require roles to authorize calls

Comment: To get there in a roundabout way (minimal effort, IMHO), keep the quarkus.smallrye-jwt.enabled=false setting, and then use the property file security realm (https://quarkus.io/guides/security-properties#properties-files-realm-configuration). Prefix each of these properties with %test in application.properties (or instead define via env or system properties) so they only run during tests. application.properties example: %test.quarkus.smallrye-jwt.enabled=false, %test.quarkus.security.users.file.enabled=true, etc, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use following quarkus configuration:

```
quarkus.http.auth.proactive=false
```

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party but maybe helpful for future visitors of this question: Since Quarkus 2.8 there is a configuration option to disable authorization: `quarkus.security.auth.enabled-in-dev-mode`.

I'm using this for the dev profile in my `application.yaml`:

```
"%dev":
  quarkus:
    security:
      auth:
        enabled-in-dev-mode: false
```

Info on this property: https://quarkus.io/guides/security-customization#disabling-authorization

And for unit tests you don't need to disable authorization but can use the annotation `io.quarkus.test.security.TestSecurity` on test classes or methods that require role-based authentication, it's part of dependency `io.quarkus:quarkus-test-security`.

Example for testing an endpoint with a security context that has an authenticated user with role `read-all`:

```
@QuarkusTest
@TestSecurity(user = "testUser", roles = {"read-all"})
public class MyEndToEndTestWithAuth { // ...
```

More information: https://quarkus.io/guides/security-testing#testing-security

Note that I also use the following config for test profile to disable the OIDC tenant to avoid startup failure, maybe you need this, too:

```
"%test":
  quarkus:
    oidc:
      tenant-enabled: false
```